# Cyclic sub groups groups proof

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I need help with the following:

Prove that every non cyclic group contains at least $2$ non trivial cyclic groups.

Comment: How is a cyclic group defined? So what do you know about non-cyclic groups?  There's no excuse here for not having provided more context, and including things like what I listed in this comment.

Comment: This question, and the votes to answers of this question, demonstrate just how derailed this site can be.

Comment: @amWhy I totally agree to what you say.

Comment: What's your problem with the question? It's a generic proof in group theory, what context do you need, and why do i have to define what a cyclic group is? Do i also need to define what a non trivial sub group is etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a non-cyclic group, hence non-trivial: one can pick an element $x \neq 1$. Since $G$ is non-cyclic, $\langle x \rangle \subsetneq G$. So there is an element $y \in G-\langle x \rangle$. Then $\langle y \rangle$ is a second cyclic group.

**Note** (Feb 1st 2017): you can even stretch the statement as follows: a non-cyclic group has at least **three** non-trivial cyclic subgroups. And it can be *exactly* three  as $C_2 \times C_2$ shows. How to prove this? See the proof above and consider the subgroup $\langle xy \rangle$. This subgroup clearly differs from $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y \rangle$, since $y$ is not a power of $x$ and $x$ is not a power of $y$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: If a group is not cyclic, then it has at least two generators.

Comment: At least this answer left some work for the OP, who, apparently did nothing on his/her own except to copy and paste the assigned question.  Kudos to you!

Comment: You don't know me, or what i did and didn't do on my own. But go on, if rambling out of nowhere makes you happy.

Answer (score 1):

we know that $|G|>2$ (and even more but it's all you need), so take any element no neutral x. $\langle x \rangle$ can't be G, so take other element in $G\setminus \langle x \rangle$, y. $\langle x \rangle,\langle y \rangle$ are no-trivial cyclic groups.